# ruby - calling a method on a dynamically named object

Tags: ruby, object, dynamic, instantiation

I have an array of strings, that represent existing object names.

```
JoesDev  = Dev.new
MarksDev = Dev.new
SamsDev  = Dev.new

devices=['JoesDev', 'MarksDev', 'SamsDev' ]
```

i'd like to iterate over the devices array, while calling a method on the objects that each item in the array is named after.

i.e;

```
JoesDev.method_name
MarksDev.method_name
SamsDev.method_name
```

how can i do this? thx.

Comment: Unrelated, but Ithink you'll have a better time in the end if you use a `Hash` instead, i.e. `devices = { JoesDev: Dev.new, MarksDev: Dev.new, SamsDev: Dev.new }`. Then you can access them like `devices['JoesDev'].method_name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`const_get` method from `Module`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-const_get) to have Ruby return the constant with the given name. In your case, it will return the `Dev` instance for whatever device name you give it.

Using `.each` to iterate the items, your code could look like

```
devices.each do |device_name|
  device = self.class.const_get(device_name)
  device.method_name
end

# Which can be shortened to
devices.each{ |dev| self.class.const_get(dev).method_name }
```

However, there are better ways to implement this type of thing. The most common way is using a [`Hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Hash.html). In your example, the list of devices could look something like

```
devices = {
  joe: Dev.new,
  mark: Dev.new,
  sam: Dev.new
}
```

Then, iterating over the devices is as simple as

```
devices.each do |dev|
  dev.method_name
end

# Or
devices.each{ |dev| dev.method_name }
```

---

**Extra:** If you want to get a little fancy, you can use the [block version of `Hash::new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Hash.html#method-c-new) to make adding new devices extremely simple.

```
# Create the hash
devices = Hash.new{ |hash, key| hash[key] = Dev.new }

# Add the devices
devices['joe']
devices['mark']
devices['sam']
```

This kind of hash works exactly the same as the one shown above, but will create a new entry if the given key cannot be found in the hash. A potential problem with this design, then, is that you can accidentally add new devices if you make a typo. For example

```
devices['jon'] # This would make a new Dev instance, which may be undesirable.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
devices.each{|name| self.class.const_get(name).method_name}
```

Comment: This is right, but it's not a great answer unless it has some context/explanation.

Comment: @Jon I don't fell like giving a great answer to someone who is lazy enough to not even bother doing correct capitalization and writing like "thx".

Comment: Did you forget `send`?

Answer (score 0):

Well one way is surely to use [eval](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-eval), a method that allows you to execute arbitrary strings as if they were code.

So, in your example:

`var_names.each{ |var_name| eval("#{var_name}.some_method") }`

Needless to say, it is very dangerous to let unfiltered strings to be used as code, **very bad things™** may happen!